# Calculating inductance value

Tags: circuit-design, rf, inductor

I'm trying to build this little circuit for a model rocket homing transmitter.  Everything's pretty straightforward except the value for L1. I'm not sure what type of inductor to use (RF I presume) or the Henry value.

The description says, "L1 is equivalent to 2 turns of #24 wire on a 5mm structure." I'm not sure how to calculate that, or even if it's enough info to do so.

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out the value for L1?

Comment: Calculations are pointless here. That's why the variable capacitor (TR) is included, so that frequency can be tuned. Besides, the antenna type and length, construction techniques affect frequency as does inductance of L1. This circuit is OK for FM broadcast band where you can hunt for frequency over a 20 MHz band-width. A failed hunt has three possible causes: (1) not oscillating (2)oscillating below 88 MHz (3) oscillating above 108 MHz.

Comment: Get a 5mm rod, of any material. Wind two turns of 24 awg wire on it. Remove the rod. Circuits like this need the precise instructions following. You are unlikely to get it to work with a random inductor, even of the right value, substituted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inductance of a coil can be calculated by this formula, which is directly derived from Maxwell's equations

$$ L = \frac{uN^2A}{l} $$

where L is inductance (H), u is permeability (Wb/Am), N is the number of turns, A is the coil's cross section area, and l is length of the coil (m).

Note that you don't have to use any metal/ferrite core, as it will increase permeability, and your inductance will be increased, too.

You can get the same inductance with a lower number of turns in that case. However, as your resonance frequency is higher than the frequency band of normal ferrite cores you can find around, it will make things complex. Such ferrite cores you can find around are usually made for switching power supplies or filtering and working for 1~1MHz range.

Use a paper, wood, or plastic stick with a 5 mm diameter.
After turning your coil, pull out the used stick from the coil, to make it empty.